# Running a Ruby script outside of my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix

I have a script that I want to loop indefinitely outside my rails app, essentially it's just writing values over serial (with the SerialPort library), Can I just us `backticks` to run my script?

Lastly my biggest concern is that the script will block requests to my rails app while its running. I want it to spawn it's own process, is this possible without using one of these Background job or Workling/Starling solutions?

Comment: Is it going to be using any models/code from your rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have shell access to the box, you can use `./script/runner 'ValueWriter.run'` to run any code with the rails environment.

You can use [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) or [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to ensure this process is running (restart it when it crashes) at all times.

Or one better, `include 'config/environment'` at the start of your script.

Or one better again, use script/runner, and wrap it in [Daemons](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Launching a program via backticks will block the program that called it. What you're looking for is Drb. [This link](http://amazing-development.com/archives/2006/03/16/rails-and-distributed-ruby-in-a-nutshell/) should cover everything you need to know.